# Unconfirmed Transactions Please help

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

It has been more than 48 hours and my transaction is still unconfirmed. I'm using Blockchain wallet for awhile now and this has been the first time happening. I was wondering what is happening? 
https://blockchain.info/tx/f7bc86411b86473f5b33a15d61804e57652a7efceed6ddd5f1d64df076467cfe

Comment: Fees is low. You can find instructions to accelerate your tx here https://www.blockonomics.co/api/tx?txid=f7bc86411b86473f5b33a15d61804e57652a7efceed6ddd5f1d64df076467cfe

Answer (score 0):

Fee is not very high (considering the period) but it's a bit strange. After 72 h many miners drop transactions from their mempools. You may try to contact Blockchain, here's the ticket page link:

https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

The fee is chosen automatically by Blockchain, so you can underline it's not your fault.

But for the future, remember you can choose the fee you want selecting `Advanced`:

[image]

[image]

Here you can find hints on the best value:

https://bitcoinfees.21.co/

And I suggest you to google these terms, so that you can make suggestions to the Blockchain's staff and look cool, and, most important, you'll learn a lot (as I just did in the past hour)

Opt-in Replace-by-fee
Full replace by fee
Child Pays for Parent

These are all methods to unblock a transaction by rising the fee, but only Blockchain can do something.

Last but not least, your transaction may be confirmed by a nice miner.

Hope this helped!